# Using "LIKE" in a SQL statement to query for words in a sentence regardless of the order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Would like to know how I can use `LIKE` in a SQL statement so that it returns the words in the sentence that I typed in my search textbox regardless of the order in which they are typed.

This is the code i use and it only works if the words are in order

```
StringBuilder mystringBuilder = new StringBuilder(strSearch);
mystringBuilder.Replace(" ", "%"); 

QueryClause q = new QueryClause("AND", "IssueDescription", "LIKE", "%" + strSearch + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); 
colQueryClauses.Add(q); 

q = new QueryClause("OR", "IssueTitle", "LIKE", "%" + mystringBuilder + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); 
colQueryClauses.Add(q);
```

Comment: You got to be more precise on what you are trying to do. Are you searching in one or more field of a table? Are you searching for one word or all words typed in your search textBox?

Comment: I think they are talking about typing multiple words and searching for all the words, like a search engine probably. At least that's what I got from the sentence :)

Comment: i have a this sentence "my dog barks at every person" currently if i type in "my dog barks" it will return that row that works fine but if i search for "dog my barks" returns 0 results... I wanna know how to make it work even of the order is not the same

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This is the kind of problem SQL Server's [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) was invented to solve.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Word1 and Word2 in your textbox you can split them and use like below.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%Word1%' AND Column LIKE '%Word2%'
```

But you'd better define a [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) and use CONTAINS to query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for multiple words you can use something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
   (Column LIKE '%word1%') OR
   (Column LIKE '%word2%') OR
   (Column LIKE '%word3%')
```

You can change OR for AND if you want to get the column that contains ALL the words instead of ANY

But is still not very useful because you have to know before hand how many words you are going to use as argument.

Maybe you should use Full-Text search feature from SQL Server [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)

Comment: this is the code i use and it only works if the words are in order StringBuilder mystringBuilder = new StringBuilder(strSearch); mystringBuilder.Replace(" ", "%"); QueryClause q = new QueryClause("AND", "IssueDescription", "LIKE", "%" + strSearch + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); colQueryClauses.Add(q); q = new QueryClause("OR", "IssueTitle", "LIKE", "%" + mystringBuilder + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); colQueryClauses.Add(q);

Comment: Can you show and example of the final query before you execute it? is difficult to see without knowing the values of the variables

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the word "foo" in column "bar" by using:

```
WHERE Bar LIKE '%foo%'
```

Is that what you're looking for?  If not, can you give an example?

Hope that helps,

John

Comment: Okay John e.g. i have a this sentence "my dog barks at every person" currently if i type in "my dog barks" it will return that row that works fine but if i search for "dog my barks" returns 0 results... I wanna know how to make it work even of the order is not the same

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    some_field
FROM      some_table
WHERE     some_field
  LIKE    '%first_value%'
  OR      some_field
  LIKE    '%second_value%'
  ...
```

Comment: i have a this sentence "my dog barks at every person" currently if i type in "my dog barks" it will return that row that works fine but if i search for "dog my barks" returns 0 results... I wanna know how to make it work even of the order is not the same

Comment: The you must have done something wrong. That SQL statement will look at any sentence containing the word dog OR my OR barks. It doesn't care about order. I think you might have a different issue then. And before you go on, I have tried it and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, split your search sentence into words (using space character as a separator). Then create a string that will be your WHERE clause like this:

```
"WHERE searchColumn LIKE '% " + splitString[0] + " %' AND searchColumn LIKE '% " + splitString[1] + " %'"
```

and so on. Use a for loop. Concat the WHERE clause with rest of the SQL query and execute.

Comment: this is the code i use and it only works if the words are in order StringBuilder mystringBuilder = new StringBuilder(strSearch); mystringBuilder.Replace(" ", "%"); QueryClause q = new QueryClause("AND", "IssueDescription", "LIKE", "%" + strSearch + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); colQueryClauses.Add(q); q = new QueryClause("OR", "IssueTitle", "LIKE", "%" + mystringBuilder + "%", SqlDbType.VarChar, false); colQueryClauses.Add(q);